# Trying to figure out why Site directory in IIS 7 would drop permissions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, nuget

So all of a sudden I couldn't run my website any longer getting server error 500.19.  Turned out that I had lost the IUSR and IIS_IUSRS accounts on my web project directory (or at least that resolved the issue).

I definitely didn't do anything with permissions either at a folder level or within IIS, and the only change I had made that could have had control that was out of my hands was installing a NuGet package (structuremap-mvc3) through NuGet in Visual Studion 2010.

I am curious on why or how it could loose permissions.  My worries is there is another or larger issue that still has looming issues and I am only aware of the one problem that I resolved with the loading of the web.config file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Could you (or someone else) have re-created the folder? If permissions were explicitly set on that folder, but it was removed/re-created, it'd probably inherit the parent folders permissions again. We generally try to set IIS permissions on the parent ("Websites") folder so all newly-created folders will inherit them.